# How to disable all zoom on mobile safari?

Tags: html, css

I have browsed through multiple StackOverflow questions, multiple web tutorials and not one has helped one bit.
I am working on a web game, and it's not working at all. I haven't tried any JS solutions because they all require jQuery. I'm honestly frustrated out of my mind at this point and need an answer.

How can I disable ALL zooming? Not JUST double tap. Not JUST normal zoom. All zooming needs to be disabled!

Here's some examples I've tried, yet do not work for me:

```
touch-action: ______;

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=___"/>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=___"/>
```

Please help! If you have any answers other than the ones listed above, then please let me know! I'm out of options at this point and need a solution!

Comment: simply: You cant. Its a browser sided feature. No website can tak control over the browser features. Would be a security flaw if you could.

Comment: @tacoshy How is disabling zooming on a page a "security flaw"?

Comment: liek I said, its a browser feature not a website feature. To disable it, your website would need permission to change browser settings/features and that would be the security  flaw.

Comment: He's right. You can't. Apple removed support for the user-scalable setting in iOS 10 as well.

Comment: Yes, but this is unchangeable from iOS settings. If it was an optional setting I would tell the users to disable it themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```css
body {
  touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
}
```

#### Information I know

- iOS Safari doesn't respect the `user-scalable=no` meta tag since iOS 10
- `touch-action: pan-y` is supported since [iOS 13](https://caniuse.com/?search=touch-action)
- If you want to disable zooming between iOS 10~12, you can use `preventDefault`, but it doesn't work perfectly

```js
document.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
  if (e.touches.lenght > 1) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}, {
  passive: false
})
```

This will only work when you pinch with two fingers simultaneously, if you move with one finger first and then use another for pinching, it fails.

Comment: add some explanation to your answer

Comment: Thanks Marvin. touch-action: pan-x pan-y; is currently still working on iOS 15.5 in 2022. It's the only way I have found to prevent zoom. However just putting it on the html/body may not be enough, certain elements with other touch actions, pointer events etc in their element tree may need it applying again individually.

For those that would say "you shouldn't override the browser behaviour which is designed for accessibility" - I would agree with you, if not for a bug that's existed in Safari since 2017 that causes the whole browser to crash: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=172206